# Content based filtering with dissimilar user interests

Tags: clustering, embeddings

I'm prototyping a system for recommending articles to users. A single embedding vector is generated for the article summary, and users self report a list of non-enumerated interests.

Concretely, a user types into a text box a comma separated list of interests. Ex: "Hispanic pop singers, Ukraine war"

Now, my dilemma is that a user could have very disparate interests, and that would interfere with calculating the euclidian distance between the article embedding and a single embedding across the users interests.

This seems like a use case for some type of clustering, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I'm open to any papers on this topic as well.